# How to disable user accounts from being able to login to other's users accounts from the same machine

Tags: ssh, permissions, security, login, administration

I have an *admin* user account, in which I am able to login normally and also by ssh having enabled 2 step verification.

I want to create a new user account, say it *dummy* account, from which I will enable others to login via ssh (with simple password authentication), but once they are logged in, I don't want them to have the capability to login in the admin account.

- The ideal would be dummy user not to have any chance to login to admin account. So for example su admin would return an error or nothing
- The less ideal would be that if *dummy* tries to su into admin two step verification is also enabled for this case too as it is for ssh logins.

The whole point is to protect admin account from dummy accounts in the same machine, and simply password protection isn't enough

Consider I am having debian based system

Comment: Don't share passwords. Explain how password protection and file protection is insufficient.

Comment: You say password protection is not good enough, yet you configure it for the root account. To me, this is a contradiction. To answer your question: You can disable `su` for those dummies by configuring `/etc/pam.d/su`. I think instructions are in the file (they are in Centos, but Debian deploys a different file). You can disable root login via `ssh` by configuring `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: @waltinator The scenario, is that I want to have access to admin through a public machine, so that's is why I have password protection, and I consider password compromised, that's why the two step verification but for dummy account I want again to give access through public machine to other people, but I don't want dummy to be able to su in admin. That is because I can consider that password of admin might be disclosed to public machine owner, and the same person might try first to login to dummy and then after through dummy to admin, without needing that  way two step verification.